# Can't post question, title problem

Tags: discussion

I don't know what to do I can't post my question and I really need some help. I can't evaluate code inline in my editor so my title choice was:

> Inline Code Evaluation in RStudio

and other similar titles. I always get an error:

> > Title cannot contain "Inline Code Evaluation RStudio". Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

I can't be more precise, that's exactly the problem.

Any ideas? Or is there a way to contact an admin?

Comment: What is the error? Can you send us a screenshot of your question? What community are you posting the question in?

Comment: Title cannot contain "Inline Code Evaluation RStudio".

Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

Comment: Hmm... what are you doing in the post or what is your problem? That title clearly doesn't explain much about your question, try making your title basically like a small sentence telling one single detail that says it all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Inline Code Evaluation in RStudio

That doesn't read like a good title to me.

Did you try:

> How can I do Inline Code Evaluation in RStudio?

Or

> What does error 4711 mean when I do Inline Code Evaluation in RStudio?

Or

> Where do I enable Inline Code Evaluation in RStudio?

In other words: A good title is a single to the best of your ability complete English sentence. For example

> I can't post a question because the title gives me an error.

alternative:

> Why isn't the title "Inline Code Evaluation in RStudio" allowed?

Your title needs to be an invitation for an expert to open your question and provide you an answer. After that future visitors will scan the titles to match with their problem. Throwing some words together to make it stick in a title is not a viable approach for those kind of users and therefor rightfully so blocked from entering the system.