# Why can't I ask a question "Why aren't all my IAM groups listed?"

Tags: support, questions, title

> Title cannot contain "Why aren't all my IAM groups listed?".

> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

What's wrong with my questioning title? It feels like a bug. I've asked dozens, maybe hundreds of questions and never seen this before.

[image: partial screenshot of error as per title]

Comment: Extend the title beyond 40 characters and call it a day.

Comment: You can add a proper answer and I'll tick it :)

Comment: I already answered a similar question before: [Can't post question, title problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350909/cant-post-question-title-problem)

Comment: Please see [What triggers my title rejection?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373415/4642212). It’s the word “my” and the short length.

Comment: It was indeed the length. The error UX is just bad. Presumably the design intent was not to tell you it's the length else you might pad it with garbage.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for digging that up. I was pretty sure I didn't grab that 40 from thin air but I couldn't find an reliable source

Comment: @LukePuplett trust me, you wouldn't be the first to add garbage  to get past quality gates and certainly not the last. Luckily downvotes and edits quickly stop that kind of littering ... ;)

Comment: Knowing the filter, you should also be able to replace "my" with "the" to get past this.

Comment: @rene Or even [the first 10, 100, 1k...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944/350567)